# Logic determine whether a set is consistent

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I got a question regarding defining whether a set of formulas is consistent in predicate logic.

For example if we have the following sets:

```
{∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x)), ∃x ¬P(x), ∃x ¬Q(x)}
```

How can we determine whether this set is consistent or not. I know that the theory says that:

Γ is consistent if there is some model M and some environment L such that M ⊧ L ψ holds for all   ψ ∈ Γ

But I am having trouble understanding this. Can anyone help / guide me by explaining it or by referencing to some good documentation? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any set after "the following sets: ...".

Comment: @Crostul `∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))` is a set  `∃x ¬P(x)` is a set and `∃x ¬Q(x)` is a set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set is consistent. Let $M$ be the model with domain $\{a,b\}$. $M$ interprets $P$ as $\{a\}$ and $Q$ as $\{b\}$. Now you can check each sentence is true in $M$.

Comment: Can you perhaps give 1 example on how to check a sentence is true?

Comment: @Rotan075 Well, what does it mean that $(\exists x)\neg P(x)$? Well, it means there is an object in the domain with $\neg P(x)$. What does it mean that $\neg P(x)$? Well it means that $x$ is not in the interpretation of $P$. In this case $b$ works.